# Is it possible to make Visual Studio 2017 to lookup for name matches in other packages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm curios if there's anyway to make VS2017 to lookup for name mathces in other packages from project's References catalog. (Like it is in Intellij IDEA).

Here I was trying to add an IModelBinder, no matches - https://prnt.sc/ncj9s3
until I add:

```
using System.Web.ModelBinding;
```

Only then I can go through all namespace of System.Web.
I would like to get match from Intellisence before I add the namespace, is it possible?

Comment: Look for IntelliSense Extender extension at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntelliSenseExtender

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box intellisense, but after you have typed the class name, it suggests you adding the using where it detects it. The scope of intellisense is limited to the default namespace and the ones explicit added to the file via the `using`.

VB.NET projects do have a [imported namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-imported-namespaces-visual-basic?view=vs-2019) feature that is kinda useful but I don't think c# ones do have it.

Edit (thanks Sir Rufo for the info): There is an [intellisense extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntelliSenseExtender) avaliable in the MS marketplace that seems useful, but after being assisted with the intellisense you would need to add the `using [namespace];` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Sir Rufo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744164/sir-rufo). This is exactly what I was looking for.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntelliSenseExtender